# gcloud dns remove subdomain NS record

Tags: transactions, gcloud

I have tried using the gcloud dns transaction remove command to no avail to remove a Name Server entry I added to a zone to point to a subdomain.

I think the only way I have found to delete the subdomain nameserver entry is to pull the entire zone file, remove the entry, and import the edited zone file.  However this seems dangerous and error prone to me.

Does anyone know how do use the gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove then gcloud dns record-sets transaction execute command to get rid of a NS entry?

I've tried this:

```
 gcloud dns record-sets transaction start --zone ${ZONE_NAME}
 gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove "${NS_0}" "${NS_1}" --name "${friendly_hostname}" --zone ${ZONE_NAME} --ttl 600 --type=NS
```

However every time I do this I'm greeted with the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dns.record-sets.transaction.remove) Record to be removed does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the command "transaction remove" you need to run the following (Modifying the content of the [] for the proper values):

$ gcloud dns record-sets transaction start -z=[examplezonename]

It will start the transaction.

$ gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove --name="[name(remember the last doc ".")]" --type="NS" --ttl=[time_in_seconds] -z="[name_of_the_DNS_zone]" "[full_name_of_DNS_server(Also the last doc "."]" "[full_name_of_DNS_server(Also the last doc "."]"

I tried it myself and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering because this took me far too long to realize:

Syntax for DATA is different between commands "gcloud dns record-sets transaction remove" and "gcloud dns record-sets list"!

When listed, gcloud returns a list of nameservers like this:

```
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.,ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.,ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.,ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
```

However, if you want ns records containing those ns servers in field DATA, gcloud expects them blanc separated, like this:

```
ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com. ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
```

That means, if you pull data of ns records with said command to use them for deletion, you must convert them like this:

```
read DNS_NAME DNS_TYPE DNS_TTL DNS_DATA <<< "$(gcloud dns record-sets list --project=$MYPROJECT --zone=$PARENT_ZONE --name=$PLATFORM_DOMAIN|tail -n +2)"
gcloud --project=$MYPROJECT dns record-sets transaction start --zone="$PARENT_ZONE"
gcloud --project=$MYPROJECT dns record-sets transaction remove --name="${PLATFORM_DOMAIN}" --ttl=$DNS_TTL --type=$DNS_TYPE --zone=$PARENT_ZONE ${DNS_DATA//,/ }
gcloud --project=$MYPROJECT dns record-sets transaction execute --zone="$PARENT_ZONE"
```

I created issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159051721 regarding this, hope they fix this in near future as it is really misleading!